# DRV8871 output voltage drop down error identify

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, texas-instruments

I'm building a brush gear motor driver with TI drv8871. No speed adjustment needed, only forward/reverse is wanted.
The input voltage is 24V. The motor has a small coil resistance about 2.6 to 3.0 Ohm, Irms about 0.6 to 0.8A. I use RLim 30K, but a 100uf 50V cap instead of recommended 47uf ( I don't have 47uf caps).

The start current is so large that always drive the 8871 into over current protection, so I added a current limit resistor of 5 Ohm 10 Watt in series with the motor. It worked last week.

But today... the motor won't start and the voltage drop and back like this : peak 10V, cycle 25us.
[image]

I sincerely need your helps:

1, What's the situation/error drv8871 into now? How to fix it?

2, Is drv8871 capable to drive such a motor with too high start current? Is the 5 Ohm resisitor workaround is suitable, or some better ways?

3, What's the best chip/way/shematic to drive these low RMS(<1A), high startup current (above 10A I think) motor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf?ts=1678371406362&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8871) shows that if RLIM is 30k, then the maximum current (Itrip) is 64/30=2.133A. If your supply is 24V, and your resistance is 2.6+5=7.6 Ohms, then your max current will be 3.15A. 3.15A is larger than 2.13A, so the current protection will kick in. Decrease the size of the resistor to something like 64/3.2=20kOhms (actually 18k for more headroom) and it will probably work.

Generally using a resistor like this isnt great, because you're wasting a fair amount of power as heat, even after the motor has started. If the motor stalls for a while, your resistor will probably heat up and melt since its dissipating 50W. Either drive the motor at a lower voltage, or get a motor driver that can down-convert the voltage

Also make sure your power supply can deal with the required current.

Comment: I got a new motor(actually by my boss) to drive: 24V, 0.8A current when spinning, but it has only 3 Ohms of static resistance. The starting current should be about 8 Amps. Any sugguested motor driver for this?

Comment: @ss1969 8A is pretty serious, you'll have to make sure the rest of your design can handle that. This search might help https://www.digikey.com/short/5274vmw8